# slow svn checkout in shared folder from virtual machine

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, vmware, svn-checkout

I am trying to perform a checkout of a folder from SVN into a shared folder that is located in a VMware virtual machine, but the connection to the svn server is extremely slow, and it often times out without finishing. A normal checkout of my svn folder takes about a minute, but now it seems to take over an hour.

The interesting part of this is that it happens only at one level deep into the shared folder structure. For example, the shared folder is **\\myserver\myapp**, and if I try to checkout the contents of a SVN folder called "custom" into **\\myserver\myapp\custom** , the checkout will take over an hour. However, if I checkout the contents of that custom folder from SVN into **\myserver\myapp\   or    \\myserver\myapp\anotherfolder\custom** , the checkout download speed behaves considerably faster (less than a minute).

So, I am wondering if this strange behaviour has something to do with some permission settings in the Active Directory of the server or folder.

**Notes**:

- I am using TortoiseSVN 1.6.15 and Subversion 1.6.16.
- The virtual machine is running MS Window Server 2003 R3 SP2
- My host machine is running XP 2002 SP2

This behaviour:

- occurs when performing the checkout from outside of **\\myserver.**
- does not occur inside **\\myserver** with svn checkout directory as **\\myserver\myapp**
- occurs even if the virus scanner is set to exclude the **\\myserver\myapp\ folder** and subfolders
- occurs even if the folder from the svn repository is not custom. I also tested with other svn repositories from different servers.
- occurs even using sliksvn libraries.

**Edit:**

- The size of the folder that I am trying to check out is 120 MB, and contains ~2000 files.
- The path that I am checking out is at a thirteen-level deep svn directory.
- A ping to my svn server is <1ms with no packets lost.
- The tortoise transfer rate is 95 percent of the time is 0 Bytes/s.

Comment: Can you update the question to include info on how large the path you're trying to check out is, how many files it includes and what the latency to the SVN server is? That would help set some expectations around what behaviour should be observed.

Comment: Try running Process Monitor, filter for the tortoise process and then look through the logs for access denied errors or other strange behaviour.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Answer (score 0):

It maybe related to the Offloading features on your network cards.  I turn this off for both physical and virtual machines to ensure the fastest transfer speeds.

I have a blog post on it here.

http://tsells.wordpress.com/2009/11/08/slowness-with-windows-2008-r2-and-virtual-machines/